# Pythonic way to group values from a list based on values from another list

Tags: python, list, iteration, grouping, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists:

```
List_A = [1, 25, 40]
List_B = [2, 19, 23, 26, 30, 32, 34, 36]
```

I want to generate a list of lists such that I group values in list B by determining if they are in between values in list A. So in this example, list B would be grouped into:

```
[[2,19,23], [26,30,32,34,36]]
```

Is there any clean way in python to achieve this without multiple nested for loops?

Tried a messy double nested loop structure, was not pleased with how clunky it was (due to lack of readability).

Comment: Where should 25 go?

Comment: Are both lists always already sorted?

Comment: What if a B-value is smaller than the smallest A-value or larger than the largest?

Comment: What if A were [1,10,15,40]? Should the result have an empty list for the range 10-15 or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way I can think of to code it.

```
result = []
for start, end in zip(List_A, List_A[1:]):
    result.append([i for i in List_B if start <= i < end])
```

It's O(NxM), so not very efficient for large lists.

You could make it more efficient by sorting `List_B` (I assume `List_A` is already sorted) and stepping through both of them together, but it will be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Group `List_B` according to the index that they would have, if inserted into `List_A`. The standard library provides functionality in the `bisect` module to figure out (by using a standard bisection algorithm) where the value would go; it provides functionality in the `itertools` module to group adjacent values in an input sequence, according to some predicate ("key" function).

This looks like:

```
from bisect import bisect
from itertools import groupby

List_A = [1, 25, 40]
List_B = [2, 19, 23, 26, 30, 32, 34, 36]
groups = groupby(List_B, key=lambda x: bisect(List_A, x))
print([list(group) for key, group in groups])
```

which gives `[[2, 19, 23], [26, 30, 32, 34, 36]]` as requested.

`bisect.bisect` is an alias for `bisect.bisect_right`; that is, a value in `List_B` that is *equal to* a value from `List_A` will be put at the *beginning of a later* list. To have it as the end of the previous list instead, use `bisect.bisect_left`.

`bisect.bisect` also relies on `List_A` being sorted, naturally.

`itertools.groupby` will group adjacent values; it will make separate groups for values that belong in the same "bin" but are separated by values that belong in a different "bin". If this is an issue, sort the input first.

This will be O(N * lg M) where N is the length of `List_B` and M is the length of `List_A`. That is: finding a bin takes logarithmic time in the number of bins, and this work is repeated for each value to be binned.

This will *not generate* empty lists if there is a bin that should be empty; the actual indices into `List_A` are ignored by the list comprehension in this example.

Comment: Hmm, I'd say this is only correct if B is sorted as well (or at least not so unsorted that the next B-value belongs into a previous group). In which case linear time might be preferable.

Comment: Yes, I covered that: "itertools.groupby will group adjacent values; it will make separate groups for values that belong in the same "bin" but are separated by values that belong in a different "bin". If this is an issue, sort the input first."

Comment: Ah right, I didn't get that. Well, my main point was the linear solution.

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind. The other proposed approaches are clearly O(N * M).

Comment: Iterating the two sorted lists as if merging them for mergesort. But building the B-groups.

Comment: Ah, I see. I can't imagine the code for that would be *simple*, but it certainly would avoid nesting loops. Perhaps you could write up an answer?

Comment: Maybe if they answer my clarification questions.

Comment: [One possibility](https://tio.run/##RYtNCsIwEIX3c4q3bDFK09SiYhftNUIWFqsNlCTEinj6OKWoDz6GeT/hPY/eqUOIKbVooKVAuReoCkPd8pcC8sieYmoBVTDsqYqpDdE9@md4LE1Dlk9BNx/Rwzp0JwLrNdppQKutwblBv5qL1unuEsLgrpk2@S@x2DSQ9C/prTTfYp8ThWjdnK1ZntIH).